# How to add a watermark to the RecordControl for J2ME working on Nokia phones?

Tags: video, java-me, camera, capture, watermark

I want to make a screen that captures and records the camera, but in the meantime adds a watermark to the video recorded, whatever this watermark is .. text or image ..
I just wanna have a way to edit the captured video in realtime.
I'm working on J2ME for Nokia.
Also if not possible for Nokia, is it possible on Android or Blackberry .. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible on J2ME *[javax.microedition.amms.control.imageeffect.OverlayControl](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-D3E35E6F-0C45-48ED-B09D-F716E14C1C02/javax/microedition/amms/control/imageeffect/OverlayControl.html)* from the AMMS API is the way to do it. Unfortunately this control is not supported on Nokia phones yet.